# C++ Object on stack or scope issue causing sigsegv fault?

Tags: c++, qt, scope, segmentation-fault, stack

Using qt5.3 with minGW, running on windows 7.

I have an odd fault where I am getting a sigsegv depending on where I declare an object.
The code that has the fault is:

```
QStringList tsetFileNames = dir.entryList(nameFilter);

// now load each in turn and put the name etc into the m_prodList
for (int i = 0; i < tsetFileNames.size(); i++)
{
    TargetDefinition target;         
    if (target.ReadXmlFile(dirName+tsetFileNames.at(i))) 
    {
        ProdListItem_t item;
        item.name = target.m_name;
        item.tsetFile = tsetFileNames.at(i);
        m_prodList.append(item);
    } else
        qDebug() << "Error updating tset list. file "+tsetFileNames.at(i);
}
```

To explain, TargetDefinition is a class which has a 
`QList<TDefVariant_t*> m_variants;"` member variable. This list is populated by the ReadXmlFile() function.

I've used the debugger With only one file present (ie tsetFileNames.Size() == 1) to see what is going on.

The target object is created with a valid (but empty) QList. On stepping into ReadXmlFile() I can see it populates the QList is created correctly.

However when it exits back from ReadXmlFile() (ie. gets to the "ProdListItem_t item;" line) I see a "not accessible" against the QList.
Then, when it exits the for loop the TargetDefinition destructor causes an exception when it hits a foreach loop.

```
foreach(TDefVariant_t* variant, this->m_variants)
{
    delete variant;
}
```

I am really struggling to work out what is causing the QList to become invalid. Target is still in scope and nothing has tried to delete the list.
Also, if I take the declaration outside the loop:

```
TargetDefinition target;
for (int i = 0; i < tsetFileNames.size(); i++)
{
    if (target.ReadXmlFile(dirName+tsetFileNames.at(i)))
    {
        ProdListItem_t item;
        item.name = target.m_name;
        item.tsetFile = tsetFileNames.at(i);
        m_prodList.append(item);
    } else
        qDebug() << "Error updating tset list. file "+tsetFileNames.at(i);
}
```

It works fine without and faults.

I am wondering if I am overflowing the stack or something similar but would have thought the debugger would have told me about that?
Otherwise, I am out of ideas. It is probably something obvious so can anyone put me out of my misery?

TDefVariant_t definition is:

```
struct TDefVariant_t
{
    QString                 name;
    QWidget*                nameWidget;
    QList<TDefGroup_t *>    groups;

    TDefVariant_t();
    ~TDefVariant_t();
    TDefVariant_t(const TDefVariant_t &other);
    TDefVariant_t& operator=(const TDefVariant_t &rhs);

    void CopyFrom(const TDefVariant_t &from);
    void DeleteAllItems();       // deletes all items from the variant

} ;                                            // Variant
```

ReadXmlFile() is very large (and involves other objects a fair bit) but the bit relevent to creating the list is:
`// first create a new variant
    TDefVariant_t* variant = new TDefVariant_t;
    m_variants.append(variant);`

TDefVaraint_t functions:

```
TDefVariant_t::TDefVariant_t()
{
}
TDefVariant_t::~TDefVariant_t()
{
    this->DeleteAllItems();
}
TDefVariant_t::TDefVariant_t(const TDefVariant_t &other)
{
    this->CopyFrom(other);
}
TDefVariant_t& TDefVariant_t::operator=(const TDefVariant_t &rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)       // only copy if they are not already the same object (ie at same address)
        this->CopyFrom(rhs);
    return *this;
}
void TDefVariant_t::CopyFrom(const TDefVariant_t &from)
{
    name = from.name;                            // Variant top level
    nameWidget = from.nameWidget;

    this->DeleteAllItems();                      // make sure item being copied to is cleanly cleared

    for (int i = 0; i < from.groups.size(); i++)        // for all groups....
    {
        TDefGroup_t *group = new TDefGroup_t;           // create the new group.
        groups.append(group);
        group->name = from.groups.at(i)->name;          // add the name

        group->settings.clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < from.groups.at(i)->settings.size(); j++) // for each setting
        {
            TDefSetting_t *setting = new TDefSetting_t;              // create the new setting.
            group->settings.append(setting);

            //CopySetting(*(from.groups.at(i)->settings.at(j)), *setting); // now done by overloaded operator
            *setting = *(from.groups.at(i)->settings.at(j));
        }
    }

}
```

DeleteAllItems:

```
void TDefVariant_t::DeleteAllItems()
{
    foreach(TDefGroup_t* group, this->groups)
    {
        foreach(TDefSetting_t* setting, group->settings)
        {
            delete setting;
        }
        group->settings.clear();
        delete group;
    }
    this->groups.clear();
}
```

Comment: What is `TDefVariant_t` and how do you create it?

Comment: Please show the ReadXmlFile function.

Comment: question updated with info....

Comment: How do you copy and destruct `TDefVariant_t` ?

Comment: TDefVariant_t added to question....

Comment: I've been looking at this again and put the declaration of target back to where it was when I found the fault. (ie first code snippet above) It no longer gives an exception! Given I have changed no other code I think can only assume this does point to a memory overrun somewhere but I can't work out where.

Comment: @Toby I suggest you place it back to where it was giving a fault, and fix the problem.  Moving code around may just be hiding the actual bug.  Basically all you're doing when you move code around is that you're just moving the bug to another part of your code.  Better to keep the code as is and fix the problem instead of potentially masking the problem, giving the impression that the problem is fixed.

Comment: @Toby sometimes you need just to rebuild a project in order it to stop segfaulting.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I agree, I only moved it to check it wasn't a scope problem (which I didn't think it was anyway). Unfortunately it is now "fixed" so difficult to debug.

Comment: @Amartel that is a bit worrying to be honest! I have done very little windows programming but if it was embedded code then my experience says that faults don't just go away on re-compile :(

Comment: @Toby I've seen this on console and gui applications under windows and various linux systems. Sometimes inexplainable errors occur which are only fixed by a full rebuild of the project.

Comment: Sounds like I am just going to have to ignore it for now and hope it doesn't come back. Just I case it was a stack issue I have changed my declaration to the heap (eg. TargetDefinition* target= new TargetDefinition etc). It is nice to know I haven't done anything completely stupid anyway ;)

Comment: where is `DeleteAllItems`? why do you use pointers that much?

Comment: @UmNyobe DeleteAllItems() added in question. Pointers are used because that is what I am used to (embedded c stuff) and I thought it was the normal way of keeping track of dynamically allocated data? I might need educating, what is the problem with pointers?

Comment: @Toby Use valgrind (http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: @Raydel Thanks for that link! I was wondering what was available for checking.